# MongoDB::Cursor object returning repeated records in perl

Tags: perl, mongodb

```
use MongoDB;
my $dbClient = MongoDB::MongoClient->new();
my $db = $dbClient->get_database( 'exp_new' );
my $rsvnCollection = $db->get_collection( 'reservations' );
my $rsvnDB = $rsvnCollection->find({parent_id => {'$exists' => 1}});
my $explanation = $rsvnDB->explain;
my $num = $rsvnDB->count;
```

The explanation is giving me

```
$VAR1 = {
          'nscannedObjectsAllPlans' => 45824,
          'n' => 33459,
```

and $num returns the same.

And I am trying to access the records like this

```
while (my $record = $rsvnDB->next) {
```

It is giving me duplicate records and while loop runs for more than number of records than returned in explanation.

Is there anything wrong in the way I am doing? Any idea why it is giving duplicate records?

Thanks
Raj

Sample Record:

```
> db.reservations.findOne({parent_id: {$exists : 1}})
{
    "_id" : 428,
    "created_user" : "george",
    "status" : NumberLong(2),
    "topologies" : [ ],
    "parent_id" : 428,
    "end_time" : ISODate("2012-08-25T01:45:00Z"),
    "reserved_ports" : {
        "bangalore" : [
            "eth 12/1",
            "eth 12/10",
        ]
    },
    "repeatInfo" : {
        "recurrEndType" : "Occurrences",
        "recurrType" : "Daily",
        "recurrValue" : NumberLong(9)
    },
    "created_time" : ISODate("2012-08-24T00:16:34Z"),
    "name" : "George",
    "start_time" : ISODate("2012-08-24T16:20:01Z"),
    "deleted" : "0",
    "task" : "ACTIVATION",
    "modified" : "0",
    "devices" : [
        "bangalore"
    ],
    "updated_time" : ISODate("2012-08-30T01:44:55Z"),
    "ports" : [ ],
    "updated_user" : "George",
    "reserved_devices" : [
        "bangalore"
    ],
    "topology_details" : [ ]
}
>
```

Comment: What you your documents look like. Can you edit with showing a few sample documents from the collection. Also try from the mongo shell to compare. But what you are doing is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After not hearing any response for I while I mused that the `parent_id` field and probably more contain a [DBRef](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#dbref) object. By default the Perl MongoDB driver [expands those references](http://search.cpan.org/~friedo/MongoDB-0.702.2/lib/MongoDB/MongoClient.pm#inflate_dbrefs) and fetches the document from the database. This is why you are seeing more documents being pulled and it probably doesn't help that your data may have a circular reference in it.

Change your call to MongoClient to fix this by disabling the behavior.

```
my $dbClient = MongoDB::MongoClient->new( inflate_dbref => 0 );
```

Giving myself a note to raise a JIRA to have this turned off by default, and leaving this here in case some **does** come across the issue, so it can be of help to them.

So now we have some sample data we can look at this differently.

This would have been very clear to various people looking here if you had included a sample document in your collection. A good point to keep in mind when asking your questions.

The behavior you mention is likely to be caused by some form of recursion as was mentioned above. Since this is **not** the driver that is at fault, we are kind of looking to your code to see the problem.

Nothing is wrong with the code that has been posted, but it notably falls short of what you are doing inside the loop while you are iterating the cursor

A reasonable deduction to make, considering that your initial query is looking for a document that has a `parent_id` is that you intend to do something with that `parent_id` in your loop. Also your sample data notably shows that both `_id` and `parent_id` are in fact the same.

So if you have any code **following** this `parent_id` then this is no doubt why you are seeing the results that you are.

Comment: I have updated the question with sample record. Letting you know that there is no DBRef Object. I tried your suggestion, it did not help me.
There is no circular reference in the records.

Comment: The only explanation is that the data is being recursed somehow. What are you doing exactly while looping the cursor?

Comment: @Raj You really need to look at the edits it seems clear now what must be happening

Comment: wow...that triggered the solution to me. Neil I think you are write, I change the document and write back to DB and cursor picks it up again and shows me as though there is a record. Thanks I changed my code inside the while loop.

Comment: I am thinking I should delete the post, it was simple perl coding issue. What do you think Neil?

Comment: @Raj It's okay. No need to feel embarrassed. We all do silly things all of the time. Leave the post here (with an accept preferably) and it serves as a learning exercise for anyone who comes across it. If Nothing else, I'd like the DBRef gotcha to be searchable until I convince someone that has to change. Glad you worked it out.